# publish error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have designed web application in asp.net...i have publish a website..
 i have create virtual directory and copy the publish file....
 and browse the website...

> An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.  When connecting to >SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings >SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 >- Could not open a connection to SQL Server) 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web >request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it >originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An error has occurred while >establishing a connection to the server.  When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this >failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not >allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a >connection to SQL Server)
>
> Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. >Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using >the exception stack trace below.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483479.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your website tries to connect to SQL Server, but the connection string is not matched. You have to change the connection string in your website `web.config` according to your hosted server.

Open web.config and change the connection string settings.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DBName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="uid=; pwd=; database=; server=;Max Pool Size=500"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: i have copy file in virtual directory..direct file change in virtual directory in web config file?

Comment: yes, you need to change the Connection string information according to your hosting server directly in your server web.config.

Comment: normally my web config file  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="PhotostudioConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Photostudio;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />how to change

Comment: Most probably, your hosting server will not have Visual studio to open these files, but you can open this in notepad and change connection string information.

Comment: @i have changed but error. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Source Error: 
 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace

Comment: Now your website is connected to SQL server. Now its coding problem, There might be Data Issue now. I think you are checking the Null value.

Comment: @ Muhammad Akhtar how to change

Comment: you have to see your code now. If you want to view the actual error, in the web.config set <customErrors mode="Off"

Comment: You have to set customErrors mode to off in your web.config to view the actual error.

Comment: i dont know how to set..web confiq file which place set.in custome error mode

Comment: Add this in System.Web section <customErrors mode="Off">  </customErrors>

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the connection string and provide uid and password if you are using sql server 2005.One more thing while uploading the published website add the dll from the bin folder

Answer (score 0):

This error might be caused because of several reasons.

1 - Make sure your connection string is correct. You can check [here for more info.](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

2 - Make sure you have "Local and Remote Connections" property is checked with "Using both
    Tcp/IP and Named Pipes" option on your SQL Server.

3 - Check your firewall to be sure it does not block requests.

4 - Make sure SQL Server and SQL Server Browser services are started at your computer.